# C++ connection to mysql error with libraries

Tags: c++, mysql

I downloaded this:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
And i linked it (i hope properly) to visual studio but i still get errors like "Identifier MYSQL is undefined". Basically i wrote 3 lines of code and i get this error (i know that i need to link the libraries to visual studio and i did it, but is still not working, maybe i have to download something else?) thanks

```
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
```

Edit:
I'm including this 3 headers

```
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_error.h>
```

And i can't include more

Comment: _"And i can't include more"_ What do you mean?

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/)?

Comment: BoundaryImposition i can't inclue stuff like <mysql/mysql.h> becouse i don't have the header "mysql.h"

Comment: No i didn't read the instructions, doing it now

Comment: "Developers using Microsoft Windows must satisfy the following requirements:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013."
does this mean i can't do it on visual studio 15?

Comment: _" i don't have the header "mysql.h""_ Why not? That's part of the distribution. Clearly if you are missing header files then that's why you're having trouble.

Comment: Inside the file mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64 under include you find 2 .h files: mysql_connection.h, mysql_driver.h and mysql_error.h, there is no "mysql.h" file, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't have the header "mysql.h"
>
> Inside the file mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.8-winx64 under include you find 2 .h files: mysql_connection.h, mysql_driver.h and mysql_error.h, there is no "mysql.h" file, why?
>
> maybe i have to download something else?

You need to install the actual MySQL library too; this is just the C++ connector.

This is clearly stated in [the installation instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-prerequisites.html), which you should read and study thoroughly before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem by following your instructions (and the guide instructions too)
This is what i downloaded to make it work https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Answer (score 0):

please check if your mysql header files are in your project's include path

```
#include<mysql/mysql.h>
```

or

```
#include<mysql.h>
```

Comment: I can't #include <mysql/mysql.h> "cannot open source file" does this mean i linked it wrongly?

Comment: By removing the 3 lines of code i wrote i get error on this 
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
"Cannot open source file"